# wget does not appear to be passing browser info, saving cookies

Tags: scripting, wget

Discover Card has a system (as do many other banks) where you can export statements to CSV format. I am trying to write a script that logs into my Discover account and fetches the CSV data using the saved cookie session. I am having difficulties where wget is not correctly passing the "spoofed" User Agent and is not saving any cookie information - either due to it's self or due to Discover's security.

Didn't know if anyone had any tips for how to get this to work:

```
userName=(retracted)
password=(retracted)
basePath=~/Desktop/discscript
postData="userID="$userName"&password="$password"&choose-card=Credit+Card&userTypeCode1=C&currentFormId=login&version=1"
postData=$postData"&pm_fpsc=24\|1920\|1080\|1056&pm_fpsw=&pm_fptz=-5&pm_fpln=lang=en-US\|syslang=\|userlang=&pm_fpjv=0&pm_fpco=1"
userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"

rm $basePath/disctmp.txt

wget --save-cookies $basePath/disctmp.txt \
    --user-agent="$userAgent" \
    --referer="card.discover.com" \
    --keep-session-cookies \
    --post-data $postData \
    https://portal.discover.com/customersvcs/universalLogin/signin \
    --delete-after \
    --debug
```

The cookie file wget returns contains this:

```
# HTTP cookie file.
# Generated by Wget on 2017-07-23 07:12:03.
# Edit at your own risk.
```

And the error returned in the downloaded HTML is this:

```
Your account cannot currently be accessed.

Outdated browsers can expose your computer to security risks. To get the best experience on Discover.com, you may need to update your browser to the latest version and try again.
```

Which doesn't make sense because I can access it just fine with Firefox when the user agent posts the same data viewing the posted data with Firebug.

Comment: When you access the site with Firefox, try using the F12 Network window to see everything that the browser sends to the server. There's also a 'copy as curl' context menu option on each request that you can use to try to replicate them manually.

Comment: The only data that is different from what I am manually posting in wget is when I log in the "normal" way via Firefox it generates a Posted cookie and GUID-like string.